# Combine class.bind with native class in HTML element in Aurelia

Tags: html, css, aurelia

I'm currently trying to combine a `class.bind` attribute with a basic html `class` into an html component through a condition. Like:

```
<a href="#" class="stackpanel stretch" class.bind="myCondition == true ? 'myClass' :''">
```

And I want to get (if `myCondition = true`):

```
<a href="#" class="stackpanel stretch myClass">
```

Can you please tell me what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify a `class.bind` along with the `class`, you can use the interpolation syntax along with the normal classes in a `class` attribute.

```
<a href="#" class="stackpanel stretch ${myCondition == true ? 'myClass' : ''}">
```